# Can't view a realm file on Realm Studio

Tags: ios, realm, realm-studio

[image]

When I go to the folder that has my `default.realm` file and open that file with Realm Studio application, I don't see the actual window and instead see a slim line like that shown in the picture attached.

When I do click the slim line, the application doesn't open a window and instead just chooses to show nothing instead. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Realm Studio application, but the same problem persisted.

Does anyone know why I am experiencing this glitch?

Update: The version of Realm app is Realm Studio 10.1.2 and my macOS version is Big Sur 11.4. If you want to duplicate the issue, first open your realm file with Realm Studio and hit that green circle on the title bar to make it full screen. Then hit the red circle to exit the window. Open the same file with Realm Studio again and it will open in full screen mode by default. Then double click the title bar and you will see your window disappear to the corner of your screen. At this point, you will be unable to see your realm file even after you click "Show All Windows" by right-clicking on the Realm Studio application icon. The fix is to go to the menu bar on the top and select Windows > Zoom. This will bring your realm file window back to your screen.

Comment: So I figured out the fix. If you are experiencing similar problems, go to Windows from the top menu, and hit "Zoom". That will return your window to your normal size.

Comment: Very happy you found an answer but I am unable to duplicate the issue. It's a good idea in these cases to include your OS version as well as the version of the App - that way future readers have a reference to where the issue is.. What version is this as you should be using 10.1.2 or later

Comment: I am not seeing that behavior. I tried it on a 27" iMac, a 24" iMac and a 16" MBP. It does exactly as you describe up until *even after you click "Show All Windows" by right-clicking*. After double clicking the title bar to minimize the window, it minimizes to the right side of the dock (if the dock is at the bottom). Then if I contextual click (right click or control click) on the app icon, and select Show All Windows, the screen changes and shows the Realm Studio window in the middle and the minimized window at the bottom, which is the correct behavior. Perhaps you have a corrupted plist?

Answer (score 2):

As explained by [@Junsu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8232551/junsu-kim):

> The fix is to go to the menu bar on the top and select Windows > Zoom.
> This will bring your realm file window back to your screen.